# A bash riddle concerning stream redirection: `cat x > y <`

Tags: bash, sh

I was given a following bash riddle with no additional information on the meaning of variables used.

```
cat x > y <
```

I assumed x and y are files. In my bash this does not execute though (unexpected newline), so I tried something like this

```
ls *.txt >0; cat file1.txt > file2.txt <0;
```

To my understanding this should put file1.txt to file2.txt and then the result of `ls *.txt`. It doesn't. It puts only file1.txt. And it's not the case of being overwritten since the result of the following is the same:

```
ls *.txt >0; cat file1.txt >> file2.txt <0;
```

My question is:

1. why is redirection of standard input is ignored?
2. why `<` at the end was incorrect and I had to place `<0` explicitly? Isn't that zero should be assumed by default?

### update

As pointed out, I've mistaken `>0` with `>&0`. The question remains valid though.

Comment: You can post this riddle also on [superuser](http://superuser.com/), maybe someone there can help you more.

Comment: @RedX Aren't cross-questions forbidden? I would have to move it there, but I don't know how.

Comment: I've voted to close your question and migrate it to superuser.

Comment: Yes, let's just vote to close by reason `This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network` -> Super User. Also, see bash manual about redirections: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about. `cat` only looks at stdin if there are no file arguments (or if one of those arguments is `-`), as per its man page.

Comment: @Cairnarvon that's precisely the answer to my confusion. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really any mystery here.

```
cat x > y <
```

You said there was "no additional information on the meaning of variables used"; that's because there are no variables used. `x` and `y` are simply file names. And the above command is an error because `<` requires a file name argument.

```
ls *.txt >0; cat file1.txt > file2.txt <0;
```

The `cat` command reads input from stdin if it has no filename arguments (or if it's given `-` as an argument). Otherwise, it reads from the files named on its command line -- and ignores stdin.

If you type

```
cat file1.txt
```

it's not going to try to read input from the keyboard. For exactly the same reason, if you type

```
cat file1.txt < 0
```

it's not going to try to read from the file `0`.

> why `<` at the end was incorrect and I had to place <0 explicitly? Isn't that zero should be assumed by default?

`0` in this context is simply a file name. There is no reason for `0` to be a default file name. If you want to redirect input from a file, you need to name the file; there is no default file name.

You may be confusing `< 0`, which redirects standard input from a file named `0` (there is nothing special about that file name) with `<&0`, which redirects standard input from file descriptor `0`, which is standard input (so `<&0` would have no effect).

Comment: Is input stream redirection source treated as file because of the cat command being used? I don't get why it would be a special case, when normally `0` is assumed.

Comment: No, `0` is not normally assumed. I think you're confusing `<0` (redirect stdin from a file whose name happens to be `0`) with `<&0` (redirect stdin from file descriptor `0`, which is stdin).

Comment: Of course I do, thanks for pointing that out. But still, why wasn't `<` interpreted as `<&0` and the error was given?

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous: `<` wasn't interpreted as `<&0` because you didn't write `<&0`. If someone writes `<` with no filename following it, it's far more likely that it's a typo or other error than that the user *meant* to type the (completely useless) `<&0`. The shell prints an error message because it's an error. Hiding the error would not do the user any favors.

Comment: true, I'm just being curious, whether it is a behavior following from the bash standard or just a feature in a given version tree. That is, is such behavior to be expected on every bash?

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous: I certainly *hope* it's standard. Not diagnosing a simple syntax error like that would IMHO be a serious bug. (I'll check POSIX later, or someone else can.)

Comment: Don't confuse `bash` with the POSIX specification. POSIX is a standard; `bash` is simply one shell that conforms to the POSIX standard as well as implements some extensions. But yes, `<` must be explicitly followed by either a file name or a file descriptor

Comment: @chepner: I'm not confusing them, but if POSIX requires an error message in this case it would be at least somewhat illuminating.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. That comment was directed at the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really have any idea regarding the original riddle.

But one comment regarding ">0"

This will redirect to a file with the name "0". You will find that you have such a file in your directory after executing the line

```
ls *.txt >0; cat file1.txt > file2.txt <0;
```

This file will contain the filenames of the two text-files.